# How to move elements of Java ArrayList to file in java

Tags: java, file, arraylist, file-io

i have a ArrayList containing some peace of command & i want to move all the elements of my list to a file.

Comment: `D:` What class are the items? What have you tried? Can you show some code?

Comment: i think my question is straight forward ,if you have a ArrayList then what is the method by which you can copy the content of list a particular file.

Answer (score 4):

Make your class implement Serializable.

Open an ObjectOutputStream wrapping a FileOutputStream

write the entire List with writeObject()

close the ObjectOutputStream.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your list elements implement the [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface and then you can use the [ObjectOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) to write objects to file and the [ObjectInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) to read them back in.

Another option you can take a look at is using [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/). You can see how you can use it [here](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html).

The advantage of using XStream instead of object streams is that using XML will provide you with something which is human readable, it can be processed by other platforms and also does not require you to implement the Serializable interface, which uses the `serialVersionUID` to store the items to a file. This could cause items which where written prior to some change to your class not being loaded. Take a look here for [more](http://c2.com/ppr/wiki/JavaIdioms/AlwaysDeclareSerialVersionUid.html) information.